# Forward client's request header

Tags: docker, nginx, asp.net-core

I have two docker images one for nginx that is used to receive a request from the clients, the request contains the client's IP address, User-Agent. The other image is an asp.net application that is used to receive the request send from the nginx with the client information. My problem is that the request received contains the nginx information not the client information. The configuration of the nginx docker image is shown bellow.

```
    server {
access_log /var/log/nginx/access-default.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error-default.log;

   listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.2:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Origin $http_origin;
        proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you see nothing in access-default.log, maybe you don't use this nginx. Try to fix it, and you problaby see what is wrong with the client information.

Comment: very little information of what the problem is; sounds like your ASP.net stuff is not handling the information it receives from nginx correctly.

Comment: Clients information is saved in nginx logs but not sent to the app. The information sent are for the nginx not the client's @cnst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is correct. I think that the problem in in your  asp.net core application. Please check the following:

> To receive IP address:
>
> > `var ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;`
>
> To receive User-Agent:
>
> > `var userAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];`

Answer (score 2):

This is miminal configuration I've used to successfully pass the request to asp.net core app through nginx:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myhost.com;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

Worked well with http and websockets. I've used it as software load balancer emulation.